How to send session specific data to be rendered from the server to the client using express APIs
I'm trying to render a username for a chat portion of the web app, which will use websockets to function. The issue is, the chat page is rendered as an api response(res.render()), inside of which the hmtl calls a client side js script to set up the websocket connection - which is where I want to access the username, but I can't figure out how to access session specific data at all from the client.
Server-side API request handler
app.get('/chatPage', (request, response) => isLoggedin(request, settings => {
        // Render home template
        response.render('chatPage.html', { username: request.session.account_username})
    }), () => {
    // Redirect to login page
    response.redirect('/login');
}); 

HTML chatPage
<script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script defer src="chat.js"></script>

          <div class="message-container" id="message-container"></div>
          <form id="send-container">
            <input type="text" id="message-input">
            <button type="submit" id="send-button">Send</button>
          </form>

chat.js
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')



  const name = '{{ username }}'
appendMessage('You joined')
socket.emit('new-user', name)

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
})

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} disconnected`)
})

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const message = messageInput.value
  appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
  messageInput.value = ''
})

function appendMessage(message) {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
  messageElement.innerText = message
  messageContainer.append(messageElement)
}

I've tried accessing request.session.account_username directly from the client side JS file, but that did not work at all. Is there a way to pass this variable over to the client side JS, or a way to access the username stored on the database another way?

If chatpage.html is a template and you've registered the template engine with Express, then you can insert the username wherever you want it in chatpage.html as display text or in a Javascript variable in a script tag that the page's Javascript can then access directly by just inserting the right tags and structure into the template file.  Remember, res.render() plus templates can render not only HTML, but also Javascript variables in the page.

The short version is that the websocket connection does not have access to session data. You'll need to implement something that lets the client provide proof of authentication yourself.

Through my research, I have found that a module called 'express-socket.io-session' exists. This only works with the socket.io module but it will maintain session data within socket 'sessions'. The basics of how it works is: socket.io has a socket.handshake object, to which 'express-socket.io-session' will add on a .session property (which is also an object itself) which contains all session data. For example, if when setting up my session I saved a username request.session.username = username like so, from my socket.io server I would be able to access it by: const username = socket.handshake.session.username. There is more nuanced involved, for the exact detials check out the npm page.
